# What is the physical significance of the determinants of orthogonal matrices having the value of $\pm 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, intuition, orthogonal-matrices

I'm new to linear algebra and while studying orthogonal matrices, I found out that their determinant is always $\pm 1$. Why is that so? What could be the physical significance behind it?

I know that linear algebra can be intuitive when visualized, which 3B1B's videos made me realize, hence I would like to know more about this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is difficult to answer. What it means depends heavily on application and context and what the matrix does/"means". The easiest example is as Jose answers the geometric interpretation that volume is unchanged. This is easiest because the first application one often learns with linear algebra is in geometry (but there exist sooo many other ones also).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It means that orthogonal transformations preserve volumes. That is so because, if you have an object $O$ and if $A$ is a linear transformation, then  [the volume of $A.O$ is the volume of $O$ times the absolute value of $\det A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Volume_and_Jacobian_determinant).

Comment: Can you please expand on this?

Comment: This is a standard property of the determinant, about which you will find information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Volume_and_Jacobian_determinant), for instance.

Comment: It is also a *major* talking point in 3Blue1Brown's Linear algebra series, so if you've forgotten it, maybe you should review their discussion of the determinant.

Answer (score 5):

Let $A$ be an orthogonal $n\times n$-matrix. Thus, $A^T A = I_n$ (where $I_n$ denotes the $n\times n$ identity matrix). Thus, $\det\left(A^T A\right) = \det\left(I_n\right) = 1$. But any two $n\times n$-matrices $X$ and $Y$ satisfy $\det\left(XY\right) = \det X \cdot \det Y$ (this is the famed multiplicativity property of the determinant). Applying this to $X = A^T$ and $Y = A$, we obtain $\det \left(A^T A\right) = \det A^T \cdot \det A = \det A \cdot \det A$ (since yet another known property of determinants says $\det A^T = \det A$). Hence, $1 = \det\left(A^T A\right) = \det A \cdot \det A = \left(\det A\right)^2$. Subtracting $1$ from this equality, we obtain $0 = \left(\det A\right)^2 - 1 = \left(\det A - 1\right)\left(\det A + 1\right)$. But a product of two (complex or real or rational) numbers can only be $0$ if one of them is $0$. Hence, from $\left(\det A - 1\right)\left(\det A + 1\right) = 0$, we obtain that either $\det A - 1 = 0$ or $\det A + 1 = 0$. In other words, either $\det A = 1$ or $\det A = -1$.

This holds for any matrix $A$ with complex (or real or rational) entries (or generally with entries in any field). The geometric intuition ("orthogonal matrix = congruence transformation") does not hold in this generality.

Answer (score 5):

OK, let me expand on my (now deleted) comment. To give a complete answer to your question, let me introduce a few concepts. Let us work in $V=\mathbb{R}^n$. I will use the notation $(x,y)$ for the inner product of $x,y\in V$ (which is $x^Ty$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

**Householder transformations:** A [householder transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation) is defined as follows. Fix a unit vector $v\in V$ and define the linear transformation $T:V\to V$ as
$$
T_v(x) = x-2(x,v)v
$$
What this transformation does is as follows: The vector $v$ defines a $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane $H_v$ passing through the origin which is perpendicular to $v$. Our $T_v$ reflects any other vector $x$ with respect to this hyperplane.

I leave as an exercise to show that $T_v$ is orthogonal.
 Furthermore, note that if $x$ lies in the hyperplane $H_v$, i.e. $(x,v)=0$, then $T_v(x)=x$. However, $T_v(v)=-v$. This means that $v$ is the unique eigenvector of $T_v$ with eigenvalue $-1$. The other eigenvalue of $T$ is $+1$ with multiplicity $n-1$ (as the dimension of $H_v$ is $n-1$). As such $\det T_v=-1$.

Another exercise you can do is to show that the combination of two householder transformations is a rotation (note that in this case $\det = +1$). HINT: Let $u,v$ are the two vectors determining these householder transformations. Define $W=\mathrm{span}\{u,v\}$. Then $V=W\oplus W^\perp$. Note that if your transformation is $U$, then $U$ leaves $W^\perp$ invariant. So your problem is essentially 2-dimensional.

---

Finally, consider a diagonal matrix of the form $$
M=\mathrm{diag}(\underbrace{-1, \cdots,-1}_{m\text{ times}}, \underbrace{+1, \cdots,+1}_{n-m\text{times}})$$
if this is the matrix of a transformation $U$ in the standard basis $e_1, \cdots, e_n$, and $T_i=T_{e_i}$ is aforementioned householder transformation, then
$$
U= T_m\circ \cdots \circ T_2\circ T_1
$$
More generally, suppose $U$ is any orthogonal transformtion, $M$ its matrix. Define the new orthonormal basis $b_i=U(e_i)$. Note that we can always find a rotation $R$, which sends $e_i$ either to $b_i$ or $-b_i$ (in other words the $x_i$ axis goes to $b_i$ axis). In the new basis $b_i$, the matrix is of the above form. In other words, combining everything we learned:

> Any orthogonal transformation, is a combination of rotations and householder transformations (i.e. reflections). One can take this even further to: if $\det =+1$, the transformation has even number of reflections. If $\det =-1$ then the transformation has odd number of reflections. You can even work this further and show that all of this simplifies to $\det =+1\Longrightarrow$ one rotation, $\det =-1\Longrightarrow$ one reflection followed by one rotation.

Answer (score 5):

*Orthogonal matrices/transformations* are essentially the mathematical way to speak about **rotations** (and/or reflections). This physical interpretation gives an easy way to see that they *should* have $\det(O)=\pm 1$.

The special thing about (certain) rotations (and/or reflections) in contrast to general linear transformations is, that by applying them multiple times, you come back to the identitiy transformation. E.g. turning to the left four times (by $45^\circ$) brings you back to your original orientation. Mathematically, this means $O^n=\mathrm{Id}$, where $\mathrm{Id}$ is the identity transformation that does nothing, and $n$ is the number of turns you have to make to be in the original orientation again. Now use some [properties of the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant):

$$\det(O)^n=\det(O^n)=\det(\mathrm{Id})=1.$$

This leaves us with no option besides $\det(O)$ being a [root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity), which can only be $\pm1$ in the real numbers.

The reasoning explained above only works for rotations with angles $2\pi/n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$. However, it can be extended to rotations around arbitrary rational or irrational angles.

Answer (score 4):

On top of what has been said: in the particular case when the entries are integers, it implies that its inverse has integer entries as well.

Other than that, the sign (whether it is $+$ or $-1 $) tells you whether the map respects or reverses the orientation (just like in dimension $2 $ a rotation would preserve the orientation and an axial symmetry (flip) would, well, flip it.

Answer (score 3):

In the classification of finite subgroups of $SO_3$, this determinant trait implies that any element of $SO_3$ has 1 as an eigenvalue, whence it fixes exactly two vectors $v$ and $-v$, called the poles. If $P$ is the set of poles corresponding to non-identity elements of $G$, then we have a relationship $$2(|G| - 1) = \sum_{p\in P}(\mathrm{stab}_G(p) - 1).$$  You can read Artin's *Algebra* for the proof of this, but the upshot is that this one equation (along with standard facts about orbits and stabilizers) implies* that the only finite subgroups of $SO_3$ are cyclic, dihedral, or the orientation preserving symmetry groups of the platonic solids.

*Implies might be a reach, but it consists of analyzing the solutions of a fairly simple (albeit famous) equation.